# Set selection of item in QStandarItemModel with Qlistview

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel

I have a `Qlistview` with some items. I want to set selection at first item at startup of window. `selectionModel().selectedRows()` returns the selectet item. But
`QAbstractItemModel().setCurrentIndex(0)` does't select the item. How could that be done like `setSelection(INDEX)`.

```
self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView()
self.entry = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
self.listView.setModel(self.entry) 
----------
self.listView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
self.listView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
self.listView.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
----------
self.listView.QAbstractItemModel().setCurrentIndex(0)     #<------ Not really working
selection = self.listView.selectionModel().selectedRows()
print(selection)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to select an item then you must use the [`select()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#select) method of [`selectionModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel):

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(
            editTriggers=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers,
            selectionMode=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection,
            selectionBehavior=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows,
        )
        self.entry = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView.setModel(self.entry)

        for letter in list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(letter)
            self.entry.appendRow(it)

        ix = self.entry.index(0, 0)
        sm = self.listView.selectionModel()
        sm.select(ix, QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.Select)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.listView)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```